# How to add a leading slash when joining with os.path.join?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
my_list = ['', 'drive', 'test', filename]

path = os.path.join(*my_list)
```

Result for path is `drive/test/filename`

The desired result for path would be `/drive/test/filename` (with the leading slash, because i do have a `'',` at the start of my_list

I ended up using `os.path.sep.join(my_list)`, which produces `/drive/test/filename` with the leading slash as desired, but i was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Absolute paths are a bit of a special case, as `/` is the actual name of the root directory, not a path delimiter like the subsequent `/`s. Can you generate `my_list = ['/', 'drive', 'test', filename]` instead?

Comment: @chepner riiiight,, ok that works.. i ended up using `os.path.join(os.path.sep, *my_list)` - if you want, please provide an answer and ill choose your answer . Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For absolute paths, the initial `/` is not really a delimiter so much as the name of the root directory. You could do the following:

```
my_list = ['/', 'drive', 'test', filename]
path = os.path.join(*my_list)
```

Whether altering how you generate `my_list` is cleaner than your current solution is, I suspect, a matter of opinion.